# Non-binary tree recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I am trying to make a program that sets up a non-binary tree with each node being connected to children. In this test example, I used a binary tree for simplicity. The input is this:

```
1
3   5
4   6
```

(Tab characters are used between numbers).
I am trying to generate the tree starting at the root (1), with its children being 3 and 5, and each of those nodes have children 4 and 6.
The tree diagram might look something like this:

```
    4
   /
  3
 / \
1   6
 \ /
  5
   \
    4
```

When I try to add children to my tree, it creates an infinite loop calling my recursion function. I've narrowed down the problem to it calling the function with branch being 1 on loop, but here is the code:

```
# input is a list of branch values
file = open("treehash.txt","r")
input = file.readlines()
for line in range(len(input)):
input[line] = input[line].rstrip().split('\t')
file.close()

# create the tree node
class Tree(object):
    value = None
    children = []
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

# adds all children to a given parent
def set_children(parent, branch):
    if branch < len(input) - 1:
        for num in input[branch + 1]:
            parent.children.append(Tree(int(num)))
        for child in parent.children:
            set_children(child, branch + 1)

# store all roots in array
roots = []
for root in range(len(input[0])):
    roots.append(Tree(int(input[0][root])))
    set_children(roots[root], 0)
```

Comment: If 4 and 6 have more than one parent, you have a graph, not a tree.

Comment: The 4 and 6 are unique to 3 and 5. There are two occurrences of each in the example. However, I suppose I have a graph if I start with multiple roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write variables in a class like you did with

```
class Tree(object):
    value = None
    children = []
```

they are bound to the class, not an instance. For `value` you overwrite it with an instance-bound variable in the `__init__` constructor but the list referred by `children` is shared by all `Tree` instances.

Delete above variable settings and use instead:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []
```